# htaccess stop processing if given directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an instalation on my htdocs folder that needs rewriterules to be processed like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin? 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/payment? 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ BACKEND-PHP/$1?domain=%1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^payment/(.*)?$ PAYPAL-API/$1?domain=%1 [QSA]
```

But now, to test joomla i need add some rule in the htaccess file that stop processing rules if the given directory is "localhost/**joomla**" in order to joomla work properly.

in pseudocode will be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

**RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(localhost)$ 
**RewriteRule ^/joomla$ [END]

# (if the requested file is at joomla directory 
# htaccess will stop processing)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin? 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/payment? 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)?$ BACKEND-PHP/$1?domain=%1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^payment/(.*)?$ PAYPAL-API/$1?domain=%1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close. Just modify your rules to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^joomla(/.*)?$ - [END]
```

The `-` says we do no processing on this URL. The `[End]` flag prevents all the rules below from firing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine off
```